# Why am I getting the error message "unrecognised selector" in my Xcode debug console

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, selector

I have a function for creating a custom button in my Swift project where I pass an objc function selector name but the code crashes when I click on the button. Can anyone pin point why my code is crashing? I get the error message:
`Unrecognized selector +[TwitterTutorial.Utilities handleDontHaveAnAccountButtonClicked]`

Here is my custom button function:

```
class Utilities {

    static func createCustomButton(withFirstPart first: String, andSecondPart second: String, andSelector selector: Selector) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        
        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: first,
                                                        attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                                                     NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
        attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: second,
                                                  attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                                               NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]))
        
        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }
}
```

and here is a call to the function to create the button:

```
    private let dontHaveAccountButton = Utilities.createCustomButton(withFirstPart: "Don't have an account? ",
                                                                     andSecondPart: "Sign Up",
                                                                     andSelector: #selector(handleDontHaveAnAccountButtonClicked))

    @objc func handleDontHaveAnAccountButtonClicked() {
        print("DEBUG: Don't have an account button clicked")
    }
```

I have noticed that it works when I remove the static keyword from the class method declaration but I would like to use static methods in my class Utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `target` to `self` that means the selector method must be declared in `Utilities`.

Possible solutions are

- Add a parameter `target` to the method.
- Extend `UIButton`.
- Extend `UIViewController` or the type the button is created in.
- Declare the selector method in `Utilities` (doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Thanks I added an extra parameter for the target

Answer (score 0):

You are using a *static* function to create the button, and when calling

```
button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
```

the `self` refers to the *class* `Utilities` not an instance.

Therefore, the selector should also refer to a *class* (e.g. *static*) function, like

```
@objc static func handleDontHaveAnAccountButtonClicked() {
    print("DEBUG: Don't have an account button clicked")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my code still crashes with the same error as before. However when I pass the target and use this to set target in the button .addTarget( ) method it works.